# Can I pack an archive with Ranchecker in the newer version?

Tags: rendering, gpu

According to the info provided by Ranch the render farm, with the addon Ranchecker you are able to pack the archive, but in the new version that button doesn't exist or I can't seem to find it yet one of the lines says I have to pack my archive before sending it to the render farm. I didn't find an updated document of the process either.

[blender 2.91](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWueP.png)

[image: older version, as found in the tutorial provided by the company]

Comment: Don't even bother using this render farm. It's been a month since I emailed them and haven't got a reply. They offer you 30$ credit to render your first project but never received that credit. People asked questions on their youtube videos and they never reply. They never updated the documents to the latest version of Blender. Zero professionalism.

Answer (score 2):

According to your screenshot, you clicked on the button "Create Archive" (which was called "Pack your project" in the previous version I guess).

Reading the logs, it says that a `cup9_16_manu.vub` archive was created. This is the file that you can upload to the render farm.

[image: RANCHecker v1.1.25 screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using an old RANCHecker version. Please update to the last one available (from November 2020) version 1.1.25

After double checking, we did not receive any e-mails from you, otherwise we would have respond shortly, as usual. Could you try again with the e-mail indicated on our website?
You can also contact us over Skype or Facebook.

Regarding the 30€ free credits, you should have received a free coupon code in the registration e-mail. I can also add the free credits manually, as soon as I know your login (e-mail address used).